# KiCad Circle Dimensions

Tags: kicad

Bit of a newbie to KiCad. Trying to get two edge cut circles, one with a diameter of 50mm and an inner one with a diameter of 40mm.

Here is my settings for the 50mm one (using 25mm as I assumed this was the radius measurement):

[image: Current Circle Properties]

However this produces a circle with a diameter of 70mm. The same with the inner circle when I set the Point X and Point Y to 20mm, the resulting circle has a diameter of 56mm.

[image: Resulting Circles]

How can I get correctly dimensioned circle cuts in KiCad?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to set one of your dimensions the same as your center.  So, in your case, set the X=0, Y=25.  With them both=25, R=\$\sqrt{25^2 + 25^2}\simeq35\$.

For your 40mm circle, set X=0, Y=20.  It would also work to set X=20, Y=0.

Note, that this is only for v4.  With version 5, the KiCad circle properties window looks like this:

[image: Circle Properties]

Comment: Thanks! I am on a Mac and don't believe v5 is available yet?

Answer (score 3):

The way I do it is, I set the grid to 1mm, put the cursor where I want the center point, hit space bar to make the dx and dy to 0(see at the bottom bar), click to start the circle and end it at dx 25 and dy 0.